# Runtime JScript error: object expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Help! As soon as enable script debugging I get this error. It breaks on the following block:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td style="width: 100px">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRun" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtRun_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td style="width: 100px">
<asp:Button ID="btnFilter" runat="server" Text="Show Elements" OnClick="btnFilter_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The cursor jumps to the last  tag. I am lost.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show the generated code, give a link, from the above I can only guess what asp.net will output.

Comment: On which line is the error? Note that you provided HTML/ASP.net code, but the JavaScript error occurred on JavaScript code.

Comment: OK, here if the full story: on page_load event I add attribute to the text box txtRun.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "enablebutton()");

Comment: And then in my JavaScript I have this function: function enablebutton()
    {
       var ctl = document.getElementById('btnFilter');
       ctl.disabled = false;
    }

Comment: The function doesn't work and that's what I want to debug but can't.As you can see in my original post this new attribute doesn't show. However, when I load the page and view source it's there.

Comment: @Masha Can you show the HTML source code of that text box? Also, check in the HTML source code what the ID of the button is. ASP.net may have changed it from "btnFitler" to something else ...

Comment: @Masha Also, VERY IMPORTANT: When you comment reply, always specify the nick of the person whom you are replying to - for instance @Šime or @Ivo. Otherwise, we won't be notified that you replied.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is that it cannot properly determine the line the error happened; it's actually somewhere else in the code, maybe because of a missing brace, comma, etc.  What JS error are you getting?  You may have to dig through your code without debugging support to find it.  Also try FireFox with FireBug, as this can really help.

**EDIT**: After reading the comments, try putting in the debugger; statement, which will cause the browser to stop execution in your method, and allow you to debug.  If IE doesn't work, trie FireFox with Firebug.

HTH.

Comment: I don't have any code on client side except for this function.